# merge two array objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have 2 array object with a student ID as a common data
The first array has data of students as mentioned below

```
[{
    _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74",
    name: 'Student 1',
    class: 'one',
    teacher: 'teacher one',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
    __v: 0
  },
    {
  _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a65",
    name: 'Student 2',
    class: 'one',
    teacher: 'teacher one',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
    __v: 0  
  },{
    _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a66",
    name: 'Student 3',
    class: 'three',
    teacher: 'teacher two',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
    __v: 0
  }]
```

There is another array object that has the same _id for each student and some data about the attendance

```
[ {
StudentName: {
      _id: 5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74,
      name: 'Student One',
      teacher: 'teacher one',
      date: 2020-05-30T02:19:10.819Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    Present: 10,
    absent: 5,
    extra: 2    
},
    {
StudentName: {
      _id: 5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a65,
      name: 'Student two',
      teacher: 'teacher one',
      date: 2020-05-30T02:19:10.819Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    Present: 12,
    absent: 7,
    extra: 1    
}]
```

I want to merge it in a way that it matches the student _id and merge the attendance data fields in the first array (an new array) and if there is no data then it should set it to 0. expected result is mentioned below

```
[{
    _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74",
    name: 'Student 1',
    class: 'one',
    teacher: 'teacher one',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
    Present: 10,
    absent: 5,
    extra: 2    
    __v: 0
  },
    {
  _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a65",
    name: 'Student 2',
    class: 'one',
    teacher: 'teacher one',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
    Present: 17,
    absent: 7,
    extra: 1,
    __v: 0  
  },{
    _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74",
    name: 'Student 3',
    class: 'three',
    teacher: 'teacher two',
    date: 2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z,
      Present: 0,
    absent: 0,
    extra: 0,
    __v: 0
  }]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you expect? to write and give you logical code?

Comment: a sample code or suggestions. Actual data is huge with more properties I just need a starting point

Comment: At least provide a proper example, in your case all elements have the same `_id` field, we can't even do _your_ homework properly this way.

Comment: @creativated ok to start with the logic start comparing the 2 array with _id property

Comment: I realized that and fixed it. Need to refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` it:

```js
var attendance = [ {StudentName: { _id: '5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74', name: 'Student One', teacher: 'teacher one', date: '2020-05-30T02:19:10.819Z', __v: 0 }, Present: 10, absent: 5, extra: 2 }, {StudentName: { _id: '5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74', name: 'Student two', teacher: 'teacher one', date: '2020-05-30T02:19:10.819Z', __v: 0 }, Present: 12, absent: 7, extra: 1 }];

var data=[{ _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74", name: 'Student 1', class: 'one', teacher: 'teacher one', date: '2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z', __v: 0 }, { _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74", name: 'Student 2', class: 'one', teacher: 'teacher one', date: '2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z', __v: 0 },{ _id: "5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a74", name: 'Student 3', class: 'three', teacher: 'teacher two', date: '2020-05-30T02:20:02.927Z', __v: 0 }]

var result = data.map(k=>(
    ({Present, absent, extra} = attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id)),
    ({...k, Present, absent, extra})
));

var result2 = data.map(k=>(
  stAttendance = attendance.find(p=>p.StudentName._id==k._id),
  ({...k, Present:stAttendance?.Present ?? 0, absent:stAttendance?.absent ?? 0, extra:stAttendance?.extra ?? 0})
));

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this with the unique _id and it failed when it could not find "Present " for a student who is not in attandance arraye. In this case Present, absent, extra should be 0

Comment: @creativated, Updated my answer, have a look

Comment: Chane id of second student to 5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a75 in attendance array
Change id of second and third student to 5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a75 and 5ed1c2d2daf8d21e26798a76 
Now try

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just needed to get rid of result map

Comment: Just make sure when deploying that your version supports nullish coalescing operator `??`

Comment: @GonsaloSousa Your answer is much better than mine. It is to the point. I have upvoted it.

Comment: @gorak I don't agree! ;) both are equally performant and produces the same result! Thanks for your +1

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the expected result

```
listOne.map(item => {
    const { StudentName, ...more } = listTwo.find(s=>s.StudentName._id === item._id) || {};
    return {...item, ...({Present: 0, absent: 0, extra: 0}), ...more};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a working example, that's it.

Iterate one of the arrays and map it adding elements of the second array if you find some with the spread operator, otherwise if no match just keep the current element.

```
let mergedArray = array1.map(el => {
  el2 = array2.find(e => e.id == el.id);
  return el2 ? { ...el, ...el2} : el
});
```